# LIBGDX : add a clickable text link

Tags: android, hyperlink, libgdx, label

I'm developing a little game with libgdx and in my about screen I would like to have a label (wrapped in a table) in which there would have a clickable text link (underlined or with a different color) like this:

You can review the code here

[image: here]

Edit:

What I've tried is:

```
HorizontalGroup monGroup = new HorizontalGroup();
Label howRotationRep = new Label("They have been based on the information provided on this ", new Label.LabelStyle(game.petiteFont, Color.WHITE));
howRotationRep.setWrap(true);
howRotationRep.setWidth(tailleCell);

Label test = new Label(" site", new Label.LabelStyle(game.petiteFont, Color.RED));
test.addListener(new ClickListener(){
@Override
public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

   Gdx.net.openURI("http://tetrisconcept.net/wiki/SRS");

}
});
monGroup.addActor(howRotationRep);
monGroup.addActor(test);
table.add(monGroup).left().width(tailleCell);
```

And it gives me this

[image: this]

Answer (score 6):

If you need only a portion of the Label clickable, I think the best way to implement this is having two Labels, this should work:

```
    Label lblReviewCode = new Label("You can review the code ", skin);
    Label lblReviewCodeLink = new Label("here", skin, "linkstyle");
    // If you don't want to provide a custom style...
    //Label lblReviewCodeLink = new Label("here", skin);
    lblReviewCodeLink.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            Gdx.net.openURI("https://bitbucket.org/batman3000/batris");
        }
    });
    // If you didn't provided the style, you can at least paint it blue by doing this...
    //lblReviewCodeLink.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    HorizontalGroup codeLink = new HorizontalGroup();
    codeLink.addActor(lblReviewCode);
    codeLink.addActor(lblReviewCodeLink);

    table.add(codeLink);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already tried this and it doesn't work if the addition of the two labels width exceeds the table width, which is the case here. Moreover the label has to be wrapped so that it can be displayed on several lines because I have a long sentence to write, not just "you can review the code here". Besides even if the labels are short enough, when i add them to an horizontalgroup they are on top of each other(superposed)(sorry for my bad english ). I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using two different scene2d labels as "you can review the code " and "here" and set click listener to second one. You can simply change the color of "here" label and position it according to first labels position like using following pseduo code :

```
label2.x = label1.x + label1.getTextWidth();
label2.y = label1.y;
```